# how to access a parameters from container in a config file?

Tags: php, symfony, containers

a dump of container, you can see that i have a parameter "linea.level":

[image: container]

my configuration:

```
  access:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/access.log"
        level: "%linea.level%"
```

error:[image: ParameterNotFoundException]

Comment: Maybe it's just me but clicking on random images is not my favorite thing to do.  Consider updating your question and copy/paste your errors and what not.  There are plenty of formatting options available.

Comment: inlined an image

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

Your controller

```
// checks if a parameter is defined (parameter names are case-sensitive)
$container->hasParameter('mailer.transport');

// gets value of a parameter
$container->getParameter('mailer.transport');

// adds a new parameter
$container->setParameter('mailer.transport', 'sendmail');
```

And your parameters.yml should look like

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    mailer.transport: sendmail
```

Send more information about your problem if you want a real help...